# How to install QGIS master using Octopi?

Tags: qgis, installation, linux

Does anybody know how to install QGIS master on Manjaro using Octopi? I've added https://aur.archlinux.org/qgis-git.git (see https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/qgis-git/) in the respository editor but this hasn't helped.

[image][image]

Edit:

QGIS is available after clicking on the alien icon but the installation fails (ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build qgis-git.).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You should probably ask this question on manjaro's forum. It is quite specific to the distro. I'd have answered you there! Glad to see another qgis user. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `qgis-git` is listed in the AUR, isn't indexed by `pacman`, and is accessed via `yaourt` usually, you'll need to click the alien icon to the left of the search bar to to enable "`yaourt` mode". Enter your search term and you should then be able to install `qgis-git`.

Re: build failure, have you tried:

1. installing all required (and important optional) packages, and
2. installing a different version (e.g. straight `qgis` on AUR)?

BTW, `qgis` rather than `qgis-git` is the better maintained development master on AUR right now.

Comment: QGIS is available now, but the installation fails. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArchGeoTux unofficial Arch Linux repository, without having to compile the packages:

https://archgeotux.sourceforge.io